# Are particulars knowable?

Tags: epistemology, ontology, theology, al-ghazali

In the 13th thesis of the *[Incoherence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incoherence_of_the_Philosophers)*, al-Ghazali refutes the claim of the *falsafa* (peripatetic) philosophers that particulars aren't knowable by the First (Principle).

Is this claim made on the basis that particulars aren't knowable by the intellect, but that essences are? That is, when I pick up a pebble, I don't know it intellectually, but by the fact that I hold it in the palm of my hand I know it by sense-data: I can *feel* its weight, small though it is, and *see* its dark grey colour?

Comment: It strikes me as similar to OOO claims about ["withdrawn" objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_ontology#Withdrawal) -- that exhaustive knowledge of objects is not possible through human interaction

Comment: @weissman: interesting, it sounds as they've reintroduced actual ontology back into the philosophical equation ie the *object*.

Comment: sense-data is quite a dangerous term, because it is very technical in the philosophy of mind ;)

Comment: @klocking: I lifted it from a translation of one of Al-Ghazalis works; I had thought he'd evocatively called it the sense-judge, but no - it was sense-data.

Comment: In the phrase "aren't knowable by the First" - what does the "First" refer to?  Perhaps I should ask this as a separate Q?  :)

Comment: @LightCC - The *First Cause*; see [Incoherence](http://www.ghazali.org/works/taf-eng.pdf), Engl.transl. 1963, page 150.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the "tricky" word here is *knowledge*.

We have that, for [Aristotle](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#AriSci) :

> The subject of the *Posterior Analytics* is *epistêmê*. This is one of several Greek words that can reasonably be translated “knowledge”, but Aristotle is concerned only with knowledge of a certain type (as will be explained below). There is a long tradition of translating *epistêmê* in this technical sense as science, and I shall follow that tradition here. However, readers should not be misled by the use of that word. In particular, Aristotle’s theory of science cannot be considered a counterpart to modern philosophy of science, at least not without substantial qualifications.
>
> We have (scientific) knowledge, according to Aristotle, when we know:
>
> > the cause why the thing is, that it is the cause of this, and that this cannot be otherwise. (*Posterior Analytics*,I.2)
>
> This implies two strong conditions on what can be the object of scientific knowledge:
>
> > i.Only what is necessarily the case can be known scientifically
> >
> > ii.Scientific knowledge is knowledge of causes
>
> [...] Aristotle clearly thinks that science is knowledge of causes and that in a demonstration, knowledge of the premises is what brings about knowledge of the conclusion.

If we equate knowledge with *epistêmê*, we have that it is hard to speak of "knowledge of causes" in the case of a "bare particular" (like a pebble).

---

Of course, a more "correct" answer has to take care of [Al-Ghazali](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/al-ghazali/) use of "knowledge" and of his interpretation of Aristotle's theories :

> Al-Ghazâlî describes the *Incoherence of the Philosophers (Tahâfut al-falâsifa)* as a “refutation” of the philosophical movement (Ghazâlî 1959a, 18 = 2000b, 61), and this has contributed to the erroneous assumption that he opposed Aristotelianism and rejected its teachings. His response to *falsafa* [the Arabic tradition of Aristotelian philosophy, from Greek: *philosophía*] was far more complex and allowed him to adopt many of its teachings. The *falâsifa* are convinced, al-Ghazâlî complains at the beginning of the *Incoherence*, that their way of knowing by “demonstrative proof” (*burhân*) is superior to theological knowledge drawn from revelation and its rational interpretation.